# For a voltage divider circuit, why does \$V_{out} = I \times Z_{2}\$?

Tags: voltage-divider

For a [voltage divider circuit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voltage_divider), why does Vout = I*Z2 ?

[image]

I understand that Ohm's Law says V = I * R, but I am new to electronics.  Can you explain this better?    Why is Vout not I*Z1?

Comment: It depends on your point of reference and choice of direction of the current. It can be \$I \times Z_1\$ as well if you choose the mentioned quantities accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

Because in \$V=R\cdot I\$ the \$R\$ is the resistor across which \$V\$ is measured. Since \$V_{out}\$ is usually measured against GND when the reference isn't marked, \$V_{out}\$ is the voltage across \$Z_2\$ in your example, and thus, the formula must be \$V_{out}=Z_2\cdot I\$.

Answer (score 2):

Ohm's law I * Z1 gives the voltage difference (informally called the `voltage drop` or sometimes called `burden voltage`) across resistor Z1. So

$$
(Vin - Vout) = I * Z1
$$

and

$$
(Vout - 0) = I * Z2
$$

By definition, the voltage of ground is zero volts. (Vout-0) is the same thing as Vout.

For circuits where nothing is changing (`DC circuits`), we use R to stand for `resistance`. But for circuits where the signals are changing (`AC circuits`), we use Z to stand for `impedance` -- impedance is essentially a resistance that depends on the signal frequency and may have a phase difference between current and voltage. , Ohm's law is usually first introduced as V = I * R instead of the more general V = I * Z, to try to avoid confusion. Electricity and electronics theory is hard to grasp because so much of it is abstract and invisible, without access to an electronics lab it can be difficult to develop a good intuition for how it works.

By the way, one of the features of electronics.stackexchange.com is very good integration with a third-party schematic editor / simulator website. Look for the link below the schematic picture "simulate this circuit".

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fGOHyE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

'I' is the current flows through \$Z_{2}\$, because it doesn't give the reference of \$V_{out}\$ explicitly, \$V_{out}\$ should be relative to the ground, so it's just the voltage drop on \$Z_{2}\$, and you've known the Ohm's law, so \$ V_{out} = V_{Z2} = I * Z_{2}\$.

Answer (score 0):

You can get there both ways.

The voltage across Z1 is I * Z1. The voltage across Z2 is I * Z2.

Okay, that's nice. Now what?

Z1's fixed reference is Vin. So, the voltage at Vout = Vin - I * Z1.

A bit easier, Z2's fixed reference is ground. So, that one is Vout = 0 + I * Z2, or simply I * Z2.

Answer (score 0):

It's all about how you define the voltage.  Voltages are not absolute, they are relative - without a reference, voltage is meaningless.  It's why voltmeters have two leads, oscilloscopes have a signal and a ground pin, etc.  You can think of the voltage as the force that is pushing the electrons in a circuit, but a force has to have something to push against.  Generally all of the pin voltages in a circuit are defined with respect to ground.  It is also possible to look at the voltages across specific components.  So Vout is really the voltage between the Vout pin and GND.  And Vin is the voltage between the Vin pin and GND.

Ohm's law relates the voltage ACROSS a resistor to the current THROUGH the resistor.  In this simple voltage divider, there will be a voltage across Z1 and a voltage across Z2.  Let's call these Vz1 and Vz2.  Since Vz2 is the difference between the Vout pin and GND, Vz2 = Vout.  And Vin will be the sum of the voltages across the resistors, since when you put things in series the voltages get added together.  So Vin = Vz1 + Vz2.

Now, if the current out Vout is zero, then the current through both resistors will be the same.  Z1 and Z2 can then be combined into an equivalent resistance Zeq = Z1 + Z2.  The current through Zeq can be determined with ohm's law: Vin = I * Zeq = I * (Z1 + Z2).  Then you can find Vz1 and Vz2 from this, Vz1 = I * Z1 and Vz2 = I * Z2.

Since Vz2 = Vout, then Vout = I * Z2.  Substituting I yields Vout = Vin * Z2 / (Z1 + Z2).

Now, what about I * Z1?  Well, there are several ways to look at this.  It is the voltage across Z1, Vz1.  It is also the difference between the input and output voltages, Vin - Vout.  It is not Vout.  However, it is possible to have the same numeric value as Vout if Z1 = Z2 and no current flows through Vout, since Vz1 = Vz2 in this case.